# Difference between bare metal (hypervisor based) and host virtualization types

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, virtualhost, virtualization, cloud-bare-metal

What is the difference between bare-metal (hypervisor-based) and host virtualization types ?

Answer (score 1):

A well-known example of a hosted hypervisor is Oracle VM VirtualBox. Others include VMWare Server and Workstation, Microsoft Virtual PC, KVM, QEMU and Parallels.
[rest is over here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/virtualization2.0/virtualization2.0_overview.htm)

Can I say openstack is relying on hosted virtualization as KVM,qemu is listed in this branch

Answer (score 1):

bare metal- Metal(hardware)+minimum things required to run an OS. So in that sense, bare metal hypervisor is also hosted.

host virtualization - On the existing host along with your favourite music player, text editor, hypervisor is installed just like an app.

Answer (score 0):

**Bare Metal Servers**

• Servers that are physical and dedicated to a single tenant

• Bare metal servers are Fast provisioning servers and custom-based servers

• They are Physically isolated, powerful, consistent, scale seamlessly.

• Ted is faster than Virtual servers.

• Bare metal servers can offer better performance and security for certain workloads and are more ideal for heavy workloads.

**Host Virtual Server**

• Easily deployed, can be created on shared or dedicated infrastructure, customizable, can be provisioned quickly, scalable, and integrated seamlessly.

• Some of the deployment options: public virtual servers, transient virtual servers, and dedicated virtual servers.

• Host Virtual servers provision more quickly and offer a more flexible and scalable environment than bare metal.